How to Pass Arguments When Entering a Scene in Telegraf.js
const calendar = new Calendar(bot, {
  date_format: "MMM D, YYYY HH:mm", // 24-hour format
  language: "en",
  start_week_day: 1,
  bot_api: "telegraf",
  time_selector_mod: true,
  time_range: "00:00-23:59",
  time_step: "60m",
});

bot.action("launchListingBtn", async (ctx) => {
  ctx.scene.enter("collectLaunchData");
});



i want to passs callender in that scene named "collectLaunchData" anyone know how to do that ??

If you want to pass additional arguments to a scene upon entering, You can attach the data to the ctx.scene.state object
bot.action("launchListingBtn", async (ctx) => {
  ctx.scene.state.calendar = calendar;
  ctx.scene.enter("collectLaunchData");
});

And inside the scene handler for collectLaunchData, you can then access this calendar object from ctx.scene.state
const collectLaunchDataScene = new Scenes.BaseScene('collectLaunchData');

collectLaunchDataScene.enter((ctx) => {
  const { calendar } = ctx.scene.state;
  // here you can use calendar data here.
  ctx.reply('Some text');
});

